# filtering date with format "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm"

Tags: excel, vba

[here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ligeB.png) the screenshots of unfiltered data

```
Sub qwe()
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("book").Range("f1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=CDate("2018/10/1 4:20")
    End Sub
```

i need to filter date with a custom format of "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm"

Comment: Do you have a problem with your code? What is your question?

Comment: the code I have is a problem cause its not working, any suggestion to help me? :( sorry i just new here and I dont really know how is that now working. Its working if the date formats is "yyyy/dd/mm" but if time included on format its gonna become this "yyyy/dd/mm h:mm" and its not working. I tried many answers i got in here but none of that help me :( or i just couldn't understand it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub test()

Dim str As String: str = DateSerial(2018, 10, 1) & " " & Format(TimeSerial(4, 41, 7), "hh:mm")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("book").Range("f1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=str

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried it. But its not working either. And the format what I looking for is not in general, it is on custom "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm"

Comment: @user10182078, I posted a question myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58199518/9758194) with a working workaround (at least for me). See how I used format to specify my timevalue? You might need something similar for your datevalue too.

Comment: does it work ? i tried to use it but still empty table has shown

Comment: @user10182078, it does work for me (obviously you need to make some format adjustments in the code if need be). Can you upload a workbook with a sample of your data? I can have a look and maybe can try to make it work that way?

Comment: sure, i just uploaded in here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h3PVzrTeSvbTiFqlbEuL2BvuHZ2ZgTWS

Comment: take a look Thanksss :(

Comment: @user10182078, i edited my answer with some code that worked perfectly for me on the data you just sent me.

Comment: Mr. Jvdv did you change any formats on the data i sent to you? such as date formats? based on your answer, where does "7" seconds in timeserial come from?

Comment: Mr. Jvdv Thank you for helping me!! :)) i just figure it with the help of your answer :D on my first try on your updated answer, its still now working. I just remove one "h" on format just like this Format(TimeSerial(4, 41, 7), "h:mm") And it does perfectly work. Thank you for your help mister Jvdv!! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I played around with your code and the filtering behavior is indeed weird in some instances. What fixed it for me is setting the `.Criteria` like this:

```
Sub qwe()
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("book").Range("f1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=2018/10/1 4:20"
End Sub
```

For this to work you need to make sure that your data is formatted like the `.Criteria`: `yyyy/mm/dd h:mm`.

Please note that this is not the format you explicitly requested in your question (`dd/mm/yyyy h:mm`). If your data is formatted like that you will need to set the `.Criteria` like this: `"=01/10/2018 4:20"`

Comment: oops my bad, i forgot that. The format i looking for is this "01/10/2018 4:20"

Comment: Then just replace the criteria with `"=01/10/2018 4:20"`, as I said in my answer.

Comment: sir M.schalk huhu its still not working, yes the code run and input the filter value on filter data on uqual but I need to re-enter or hit ok button first to appear what i filter

Comment: So what exactly happens when you run the code? Do you get an empty table with all data filtered out?

Comment: I'd need a screenshot of your unfiltered data for further advice

Comment: Mr m.schalk i got link of screenshot above of my post. Please check it :) thank youuu

Comment: Thanks, but I need a screenshot of your data BEFORE applying the filter.

Comment: here's the image mr.Schalk https://i.stack.imgur.com/ligeB.png. sorry bout' that hehe

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure the date "01/10/2018 4:20" is in your data? Everything else looks fine. You could also use the alternative answer provided by JvDV

Comment: This whole filter story becomes a funny side-quest for me now. I'm on a system that uses local comma as decimal point and something like  `Dim SearchNum As Double: SearchNum = DateValue("01/10/2018") + TimeValue("4:20")` and then use `SearchNum` as criteria would not work for me. Strange.

Comment: It also did some funky stuff on my system. I applied a filter via VBA, which left me with a blank table. Then when I copied the criteria that were applied and compared it to my table via worksheet functions it found all the correct matches.

Comment: I asked the community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58199518/9758194). Not sure you had the same issue.

Comment: yeap, im sure that date value is in my data. and before i doing this algo im testing it by manual to sure there’s gonna be results

Comment: just to add, i just figured that it cant filter by custom format. I tried changing all the date format to "short date" which is "dd/mm/yyy" (01/10/2018). and changing a bit of code .Criteria1:=CDate("2018/10/01"). And it works fine. But i still need the custom format to filter perfectly :(