# AutoFilter DateTime values - Local decimal point issue

Tags: excel, vba, filter, formatting, autofilter

***Background***

While I was trying to solve a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58196880/9758194) for another user I ran into, seemingly, a local issue.

Imagine some very simple sample data (being true date-time values):

```
| DateTimeVals   |
|----------------|
| 1-1-2019 01:00 |
| 2-1-2019 01:00 |
| 3-1-2019 01:00 |
| 4-1-2019 01:00 |
| 5-1-2019 01:00 |
```

It doesn't need to be more complicated to show you the issue at hand. Let's imagine we would want to filter on `3-1-2019 01:00` (3rd of Jan). Simply using:

```
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="3-1-2019 01:00"
```

Works just fine, A hardcoded string variable does work, but I thought about something more dynamic filtering on the true numeric values as below.

---

***Code***

```
Sub test()

Dim SearchNum As Double: SearchNum = DateValue("3-1-2019") + TimeValue("1:00")
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & SearchNum, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & SearchNum

End Sub
```

Keeping an eye out on this variable through `WATCHES` shows the following:

[image]

But the filter applied shows 0 results:

[image]

And here is the odd part, the filter applied tells me that I apparently filtered between the full value without a decimal comma.

[image]

Manually adding the comma to this number made the number turn into a formatted date/time value. But no result is shown.

---

***Workaround***

I've found a way around it using the following code:

```
Sub test()

Dim str As String: str = DateSerial(2019, 1, 3) & " " & Format(TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), "hh:mm")
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=str

End Sub
```

---

***Question***

While I did read about how MS might have neglected the `AutoFilter`, I'm thinking my issue described must have something to do with local settings. How would `VBA` insert the criteria as a whole number? And how to avoid it? Any other way around than my workaround (or a helper column)?

---

***Note:***

- Changing the long number by manually inserting a comma changed the value in the correct date/time formatted value.
- Working with a `TimeValue` is prone to floating point errors, as `1:00` has much more decimals then the shown ones. Inserting the full numeric value in a string variable solved the disappearance of the comma and showed a formatted date/time value, however no result is shown.

Comment: Check that one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: Probably comma (",") disappeared, because it comma is set as digit grouping symbol in your regional settings.

Comment: @Teamothy, comma is my decimal delimiter while point is the grouping symbol. However playing around with that didn't help either. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'm now at the point where I know there must be a floating point error as `1:00` is actually `0,0416666666666667`. Putting `43467.0416666666666667` as criteria actually showed up as `3-1-2019 1:00` in the filter, however no result is shown....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `ROUND()` pior to giving the varaibles?

As you don't need the seconds in your filter you can make a workaround by rounding and that maybe gives "exact" values for finding within the filter.